# Discovering the reason for File.mkdirs() failure

Tags: java, file, io, directory

If I call one of the methods `File.mkdir()` or `File.mkdirs()` in Java, and it returns `false`, is there a way to know why was the directory not created?

Comment: I've always wondered why `mkdir()` was designed the way it did (not that it ever was a problem for me).

Comment: Same with `delete()`, just returns a boolean. No indication of why something failed if it's not a `SecurityException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, no. If a `SecurityException` is NOT thrown, then the most likely cause is a typo in the path, meaning you've accidentally specified a parent path to the new directories that is somehow invalid.

I don't suppose you have it wrapped in a `try { ... } catch (Exception e)` block, where you don't realize a `SecurityException` is being thrown, because you're catching an ancestor of `SecurityException`, do you?

If you have a high belief that everything looks right, and it still fails, I suppose you could simply put it in a loop to retry, say, three times. If it still fails, and depending on your application, you might raise some kind of alert at the UI level, or log the error in a log file (assuming you can write to it).

I suppose it's possible that some deeper I/O issue is preventing it from working, but beyond simply notifying the user of a failure there isn't much you can (or really should) do at an application level. If there's something deeper in the I/O wrong, that's more likely a problem with the system/hardware/OS, or something completely wonky that you have no control over like a subsystem/service crash.

...and if that's happening, that's the responsibility of the IT guy to fix, not your application. Unless of course your app is somehow causing the crash.

Comment: No, that was not the case. I discovered the problem (the parent directory had a wrong owner in one node of a cluster) but it required to me to go to another floor, talk to the network admin, ask someone to give me an ssh session and, finally, type `mkdir my/faulty/path`. I hoped for a more practical way of doing it...

Comment: Well there you go - IT guy problem. :)

Comment: all functions should return error codes so you can find out if it's an io error or permissions problem not just "failed." this is really a poor interface.

Answer (score 0):

I had a mkdirs() failure on windows on a UNC path.
The code looks like this:

```
public File getOldDirectoryPath(String root, String name)
{   
    File fulldir = new File(root, name)
    boolean created = false

    int retry = 0
    while (!created) {
        retry++
        if (!(created = fulldir.exists())) {
            if (20 == retry) break 
            if (!fulldir.mkdirs()) {
                sleep(100)
                fulldir = new File(root, name)
            }
        }
    }
    return fulldir.exists() ? fulldir : null
}
```

There appears to be some sort of caching involved where exists() returns false (does not exists) but the mkdir on the file system fails because it does exist.  Recreating the File() entry or lengthing the timeout did not make a difference.

I discovered a plugin on elasticsearch to fix a SMB problem on Windows.  Researching the solution, it uses nio.file instead of io.File.  Rewriting the function fixed the issue:

```
public File getDirectoryPath(String root, String name)
{   
    Path fulldir = Paths.get(root, name)
    boolean created = false

    int retry = 0
    while (!created) {
        retry++
        if (!(created = Files.isDirectory(fulldir))) {
            if (20 == retry) break
            try {
                Files.createDirectories(fulldir)
            } catch (Throwable thx) {
                // error handling
            }
        }
    }
    return fulldir.toFile()
}
```

createDirectories() sometimes fail, but recovers where mkdirs() does not.